# Xpath - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"preheader-row-1\"]//tbody/tr/td//a//b"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

For some reason I'm unable to find the `xpath` for the following element of the email template through the `selenium webdriver` , I'm facing the "`no such element: Unable to locate element"` error though the manual `xpath` works fine on browser F12 mode.

The full xpath is :

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a/b
```

[image: Full HTML of the page]

Comment: I've tried xpath is //*[@id=\"preheader-row-1\"]//tbody/tr/td//a//b which is working manually however it has failed using the script.

Answer (score 0):

If text is not gonna change, then use this :

```
//b[text()='Get Started']
```

Comment: Well thats not even working I’ve tried that one at first i guess its just not excepting the xpath and even tried the class name but its the same result.

Comment: How would I have gotten to know that you have tried ? You never mentioned that in your post at first place.